# How do I format selected inline text as a specific language?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometime I have string literals that are json or yaml or sometimes other formats.

I want to just highlight some selected text and apply a specific language formatter to it. Is this possible?

I have been copying said strings to temp.json/temp.yaml files, saving to format, then copying back into my code. I would like to just highlight this text inline and have vscode format it in whatever file I am currently in.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. If I were you, I'd consider saving the text externally and having your program read it in.